# How do I use MAUD for phase quantification of XRD data with AMCSD standards?

Tags: software, x-ray-crystallography

I'm a biologist with some raw powder XRD data of biominerals, need to quantify different phases, can't access commercial software or databases at the moment.

Does anyone have experience with using the cif standards from the AMCSD with MAUD? It seems to display the list of phases fine, but when I pick one it doesn't load.

Alternatively, suggestions of other free/trial software that works on Win 7, accepts the AMCSD and is not too impenetrable to noobs would be welcome. I have tried XPowder12 trial (which kept crashing), FullProf (which I couldn't figure out), and GSAS (which I couldn't even install). MAUD seemed like such a nice program until it didn't load the standards...